# DisplayPorts on GPU suddenly not working on certain monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I have no idea what is going on but after a morning of troubleshooting I am at a loss. I am running on Windows 10 Home latest (Microsoft Windows 10 Home, Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363).

I have a [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/rtx-2080-ti/), it has 3 DisplayPorts and 1 HDMI input.

Up until this morning I had this setup:

- **Main**: 4K 144hz DisplayPort Monitor.
- **Satellite**: 144hz DisplayPort Monitor.
- **Satellite 2**: 60hz HDMI Monitor.

The last DisplayPort I use for my [Valve Index](https://store.steampowered.com/valveindex/) VR headset when I am playing.

This morning the main display would not work, I tried swapped cords around on different ports, I did a fresh uninstall and reinstall of the latest display driver. I used a HDMI (Monitor) to display port (PC) cable on my DisplayPort Satellite monitor to see if it was the cord since I did not have an extra DisplayPort cable and it then let my main and satellite to work, the HDMI is no longer working now but I have my 2 main ones.

I then ordered a new DisplayPort cable for my main monitor to see if it was an issue with the cable, but plugging it in immediately turns off my main display and my HDMI monitor comes back on, I am so baffled on what is happening.

I can actually get it to work in a very specific port configuration and if I unplug the HDMI from the 3rd satellite the main monitor stops working again, so I temporarily have a fix but I occasionally hook up my satellite monitor to a laptop and would like to still solve the root problem.

Thanks in advance for any help, here is my system info:

```
System Information report written at: 10/06/20 12:31:00
[System Summary]

Item    Value   
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home   
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363  
Other OS Description    Not Available   
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation   
System Name GMAN-PC 
System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.   
System Model    Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI 
System Type x64-based PC    
System SKU  Default string  
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz, 3601 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)  
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. F11, 10/15/2019    
SMBIOS Version  2.8 
Embedded Controller Version 255.255 
BIOS Mode   Legacy  
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.   
BaseBoard Product   Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI-CF  
BaseBoard Version   x.x 
Platform Role   Desktop 
Secure Boot State   Unsupported 
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible    
Windows Directory   C:\Windows  
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32 
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume11    
Locale  United States   
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.18362.752"  
User Name   GMAN-PC\GMan    
Time Zone   Central Daylight Time   
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB 
Total Physical Memory   31.9 GB 
Available Physical Memory   17.0 GB 
Total Virtual Memory    41.9 GB 
Available Virtual Memory    18.6 GB 
Page File Space 10.0 GB 
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys 
Kernel DMA Protection   Off 
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled 
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable    
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes 
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes 
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes 
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes 

[Hardware Resources]



[Conflicts/Sharing]

Resource    Device  
Memory Address 0x55300000-0x55303FFF    Standard NVM Express Controller 
Memory Address 0x55300000-0x55303FFF    Intel(R) PCI Express Root Port #17 - A340   
        
I/O Port 0x000003C0-0x000003DF  Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
I/O Port 0x000003C0-0x000003DF  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
I/O Port 0x00000070-0x00000070  Motherboard resources   
I/O Port 0x00000070-0x00000070  System CMOS/real time clock 
        
IRQ 11  Intel(R) SMBus - A323   
IRQ 11  Intel(R) Thermal Subsystem - A379   
        
I/O Port 0x00003000-0x00003FFF  Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
I/O Port 0x00003000-0x00003FFF  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
Memory Address 0x52000000-0x550FFFFF    Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
Memory Address 0x52000000-0x550FFFFF    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
Memory Address 0x55200000-0x552FFFFF    Intel(R) PCI Express Root Port #9 - A330    
Memory Address 0x55200000-0x552FFFFF    Standard NVM Express Controller 
        
IRQ 16  High Definition Audio Controller    
IRQ 16  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
Memory Address 0x40000000-0xDFFFFFFF    PCI Express Root Complex    
Memory Address 0x40000000-0xDFFFFFFF    Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
Memory Address 0x40000000-0xDFFFFFFF    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
Memory Address 0xA0000-0xBFFFF  PCI Express Root Complex    
Memory Address 0xA0000-0xBFFFF  Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
Memory Address 0xA0000-0xBFFFF  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti  
        
I/O Port 0x000003B0-0x000003BB  Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901   
I/O Port 0x000003B0-0x000003BB  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
```

Comment: Are you using the [latest driver version](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/165686/en-us)?

Comment: @harrymc Yes the latest

Comment: Please add to your post an orderly list of ports and monitors (with models) for each configuration that works or not. It's hard to understand it from your current description.

Comment: what is your refresh rate ?  check in  Display Settings>
Advanced Display Settings>
Select monitor icon>
Display Adapter Settings>
'Monitor'>
Set Refresh Rate>

Comment: what is your windows 10 build version ? I guess some windows 10 build version have issue for this item and need to downgrade , do you have any other windows 10 version to test ?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds very obvious, but have you simply tried rebooting the PC?

Comment: Is there GSync Enabled on the monitors? if yes, Try after disabling it :)

Comment: I will try this and let you know. I do have gsync enabled on my primary display.

Comment: Windows version is in my saying I on the post. Refresh is 144, 144 and 60. Also yes I rebooted multiple times.

Comment: In my case, I had to **press on/off button** on the monitor. Simply switching AC power on/off was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, which you may not like: the card may be physically damaged, as mine appears to be. (Please note: I have a 2080 OC, which is a step down from the 2080 Ti, but appears to have the same DisplayPort setup as many other 2XXX series [and other series] from NVIDIA as well). My monitor setup was similar to yours and I also was using one of my last DisplayPorts for a VR headset (although Oculus instead of Valve).

My problems began with my monitor suddenly not working, at first it seemed as though I could swap some cables around and get something working, but the situation has quickly deteriorated into only the USB-C port and the HDMI port working, and none of the DisplayPorts.

I have done everything, including using other operating systems running off different drives, and now a new version of Windows to verify that in fact all the DisplayPorts are simply issuing no signal.

I see extensive reports online of others whose NVIDIA cards are physically damaged and unable to give a signal on DisplayPort. If I had a similar backup card, I would send this one out for repair, but I don't, and if you were able to get yours repaired, I'm sure many would appreciate a status update.

It's possible your answer turns out to be different from mine, but at this point I seriously doubt it. It's been almost a year of researching and dealing with this problem. My only workaround was to get a USB-C monitor, which isn't bad, but it's not a great solution. I'm a graphic designer and I don't believe that desktop monitors should be less than 15" across, ever.